# Query a subset of an array in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to subset a SQL query in snowflake based on elements of an array in one of my columns, but not sure how to do that.

For instance if column2 were an array data type that looked like this

```
SELECT column2
FROM table
LIMIT 7;
```

with output:

```
Row column2
1 ["cats","dogs"]
2 ["horses","cows","cats"]
3 NULL
4 ["dogs","fish]
5 ["birds"]
6 ["cats"]
7 NULL
```

And I wanted to subset the data and run a query that pulled in any row that had "cats" as an element in any of the arrays in column 2 -so rows 1,2, and 6- how would I construct that query?

Using something like this doesn't work:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM Table
WHERE column2 = "cats" (or using an IN statement)
```

and results in an error message as an invalid identifier "cats" which I would expect since it is in an array

any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ARRAY_CONTAINS()` works, but you have to be careful with types.

For example, this one returns false:

```sql
select array_contains('2020-01-01'::date::variant
    , array_construct('2020-01-01', '2019-01-01'));
```

But these return true:

```sql
select array_contains('2020-01-01'::date::string::variant
    , array_construct('2020-01-01', '2019-01-01'));


select array_contains('2020-01-01'::date::variant
    , array_construct('2020-01-01'::date, '2019-01-01'));
```

In the case of strings, this one returns a compilation error (as you saw):

```sql
select array_contains('cats'
    , array_construct('cats', 'dogs'));

-- SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 Invalid argument types for function 'ARRAY_CONTAINS': (VARCHAR(4), ARRAY)
```

But this one fixes it:

```sql
select array_contains('cats'::variant
    , array_construct('cats', 'dogs'));
```

Comment: Ok, interesting. So the `::variant` is indicating that there are other elements in the arrays as well? Would I have to explicitely declare what all they are such as in the statement `array_construct('cats', 'dogs'))`? That makes it difficult querying when different rows have arrays with different sets of elements that include 'cat' as well `["horses","cows","cats"]` or just `["cat"]` or for that matter the many columns I don't actually know which other elements are with cats.

Comment: my apologies I meant `"cats" with an 's' at the end. I did not intend to make the words different with some being singular and plural, and they're all meant to be the same and plural. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure what this question means. I used `array_construct` because I don't have a table with an array like you already have. Did you try `where array_contains('cats'::variant, column2)`?

Comment: One final question. Is it possible to include 'cats' while simultaneously excluding another element say 'horses'? So, creating a query that includes rows 1 ["cats","dogs"] and row 6 ["cats"] but excludes row 2 because you do not want any row that has "horses" in it even if "cats" is part of that array?

Comment: let's do that as a new question ;)

Answer (score 5):

You want [`array_contains()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html):

```
where array_contains('cats'::variant, column2)
```

Comment: So, when I do that on my actual query, I get `SQL compilation error: line 6 at position 4 invalid argument types for function 'ARRAY_CONTAINS: (VARCHAR(9), ARRAY).` The data inside the arrays are in double quotes if that makes a difference.

Comment: `array_contains` will work, but you need to be aware of types, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278871/132438

Answer (score 0):

The array_contains will let you answer your specific question, however I thought it might be useful to see how you can transform the array into something that looks more like a table.

The lateral [flatten](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) functions in snowflake are definitely worth taking a peak at if you're using arrays.

[image]

```
with cte as (
  select 'some other info_1' col_1 ,ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('cats','dogs') col_2  
union select 'some other info_2' col_1 ,ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('horses','cows','cats')
union select 'some other info_3' col_1 ,NULL
union select 'some other info_4' col_1 ,ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('dogs','fish')
union select 'some other info_5' col_1 ,ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('birds')
union select 'some other info_6' col_1 ,ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('cats')
union select 'some other info_7' col_1 ,NULL )

select col_1, animals.value from cte ,lateral flatten(col_2) animals 
where animals.value = 'cats';
```